# Preventing Duplication in database, not ID column

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I´ve been using Stack Overflow all summer to get my webpage project online, and I've had enough of it so I have made it public. However I have one little stone in my shoe that I'd like to fix.

I have tried all the INSERT IGNORE suggestions found here, to prevent duplicate data entry in a row other than the ID (which is the primary column). My webpage is www.lostdots.com , and I want to prevent someone entering the same domain name twice as it will make the database look untidy.

I have used:

```
   PRIMARY KEY (id, namebox1))");
   foreach($form_data as $name=>$value)
   {
     mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $mysql_table ADD $name VARCHAR(255)");
    }
   mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO 
       $mysql_table  (`DATESTAMP`, `TIME`, `IP`, `BROWSER`)
            VALUES ('".date("Y-m-d")."',
            '".date("G:i:s")."',
```

I understood that by making the 'namebox1' a primary key it would prevent duplication, and the 'Insert ignore' will prevent reporting the error. So what am I doing wrong? I know I should have already moved on into MySQLi, but I'd like to get over one bridge at a time. Any ideas GURUs?

thanks,
Alastair

Comment: is the row you dont want to have duplacte entries in unique?

Comment: I think so. I have learnt how to run a little in code, but I should have walked first. The domain names are user entered, and to prevent someone adding their name to advertise more than once I wanted to prevent duplication. But I'm stumped.

Comment: try ALTER TABLE `table_name`
 ADD UNIQUE INDEX `domain_name_column` (`domain_name_column`); to make the column values unique then INSERT IGNROE should work

Comment: Will try that. Do I need to enter specific values, for example like you can see in the above code for 'Datestamp'? And will this cause any issues to the auto increment of the ID column? Ta.

Comment: you just have to replace the column names with your names. your just adding the unique functionality to this column. the other columns are not effected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just setup a unique index on the column.

IF you have PHPMyAdmin just click on "unique" under the column you want to set unique. You find that button under "structure" overview of the target table.

Incase you do not have PHPMyAdmin you can solve this by altering your schema with a raw query:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD UNIQUE (`column_name`);
```

And voila, you're done. MySQL won't accept any further duplicate values within the target column.

Ofcourse you should validate your insert with a forgoing select inform of a ("email is already taken" or whatever this unique index is for) function and generate a custom error message because ofcourse if you are trying to insert a duplicate value mysql will throw an error and this can confuse u and the user, especially if you are using constructs such as

```
$result = mysql_query(...);
if($result == false) die("An error occured");
```

Beware that this will work only if the integrity required for the index is given, pretty much means: There must be no duplicate values in the table at the moment or you cannot setup the index. If you already got duplicate data in the table you should think about if its possible to drop the data or change all the keys manually.

(Remember that if the column is set-up nullable (it contain NULL values) that this value may always appear multiple times regardless what the index is telling).

At the very last to be mentioned: mysql_query is a deprecated library and will be removed in the future. Please consider upgrading to more save, more performant and more easy to handle libraries http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php or http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Cheers Chaps. New ideas to try. Thought I was truly stuck.

Comment: I was thinking maybe a MySQL trigger?

Comment: Sounds good, I'll play with both these options, so thanks Steini & Andre

Comment: A trigger is clearly overkill here, A trigger is required if you want to fire custom actions that must be performed aside when data are updated or inserted that cannot be accomplished with basic schema or inno-db features such as foreign key constraints or indexes.

Comment: DONE. Thanks, I've already tested this, and it stated "Failed to update table!
Duplicate entry 'netnom.com' for key"

Comment: WONDERFUL STUFF. Viva le STACK OVERFLOW, been trying to do this for the last 2 months. 1 Question, and 10 minutes later sorted. If I was rich I'd reward you all. Thanks.

Comment: Got a problem !! This creates a blank data entry, any way to avoid this?

Comment: The blank data entry must exist from before. MySQL wont insert any data when a unique index doesnt allow the insert.

Comment: The original entry is unchanged, thanks Steini, think I'll have to modify the webpage to not show the blank data rows.

Comment: Okay, so all the data from the duplicate entry was NULL after insert, however the ID auto incremented to 63 (next domain name), can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Make your domain_name column UNIQUE.

For better: Please try to select data from table on domain name. if row count is greater than 0 then this mean domain name is already exist in table.
if not then insert.

so use both for UNIQUE and select query.

Comment: Can you imagine that if someone is asking for such a solution he has no idea what a database index is? So telling him to put his table unique wont solve anything. Better help out by telling what him how to set it up or you can place your hint in a comment.

Comment: I don't know about database indexes? I only have 1 database for this website, maybe I should split the form data?

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I can lookup database index, and learn about it so thanks, any suggestion is welcome. After all its my problem to work it through and understand for the next time.

Comment: very gud: please check this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-indexes.htm